# Match string but don't repeat after matched once

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to match the following string using regex

```
PathInfo: /words-words-words/-/orders/124141414141_1/meme
```

But once it matches this string once I want it to ignore any other matching strings afterward. Is this possible?

Edited:

I am trying to get the following pattern in regex if possible

PathInfo: /words-words-words/-/orders/**Numbers**/meme

So I want to capture this string... the numbers changes frequently but once it captures and outputs the numbers once I don't want it to capture it again?

Comment: Not a job for regex, it just matches. You're best bet is to globally match into an array, then remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood what you wanted, but if you do the following you can extract whatever number is in a path with the format that you posted in your example:

```
echo '/words-words-words/-/orders/124141414141_1/meme' | sed 's,.*/\([[:digit:]]*_[[:digit:]]*\)/.*,\1,g'
```

Outputs:

```
124141414141_1
```

Comment: This looks just about what I need...Where can I test this?